# CakePHP 3.3.0 not updating hasOne table

Tags: php, cakephp, orm

I have the following function:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $resident = $this->Residents->get($id, [
        'contain' => [ 'ResidentGeneral' ]
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $resident = $this->Residents->patchEntity($resident, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Residents->save($resident)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The resident has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The resident could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

    $titles = $this->Residents->ResidentGeneral->Titles->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $sexes = $this->Residents->ResidentGeneral->Sexes->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $maritalStatuses = $this->Residents->ResidentGeneral->MaritalStatuses->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $rooms = $this->Residents->ResidentGeneral->Rooms->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $nationalities = $this->Residents->ResidentGeneral->Nationalities->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $ethnicOrigins = $this->Residents->ResidentGeneral->EthnicOrigins->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);

    $this->set(compact('resident', 'titles', 'sexes', 'maritalStatuses', 'rooms', 'nationalities', 'ethnicOrigins'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['resident']);
}
```

The add function is identical with the exception of

```
     $resident = $this->Residents->get($id, [
        'contain' => [ 'ResidentGeneral' ]
    ]);
```

being instead

```
    $resident = $this->Residents->newEntity();
```

and $id = null missing from the top.

Now the add function will save to the database correctly and to the residentsGeneral table with out an issue however edit will not update, they are using the same form so all conventions are being kept.

The documentation on this states that patch and save both work one layer down with associations and even so add would not work if they didn't, also since the add function works, this means all models work correctly as well however this will not update any associated records in the table.

As you can probably see most of this code is baked so this is how the framework is intended to run.

Any help would be fantastic since I am one stage away from a broken PC.

Comment: I'm having problems saving associations (belongsToMany) also in 3.3, went back  to 3.2.14 and it worked.  I have no clue why, same code.

Comment: I found the same on another developer's PC, he could edit with 3.2.X however not with 3.3.X, is there a possible issue with the core?

Comment: Just tried with a fresh install with 2 tables and a hasOne between them, same thing, no updating content, will raise an issue on github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it has already been fixed on the master branch and will be fixed in cakephp 3.3.1